# How to send logo in the body of email in php?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am attaching my email code. I want to add an image in my body section with a message in this code.

```
require_once "../lib/Mail-1.4.1/Mail.php";

$from = 'someone@gmail.com';
$to = $mail;
$subject = 'Account Confirmation';
$body = 'Thanks for registering yourself, your login credentials are as 
follows;'."\r\n".'Your User Name is: '.$uname.''."\r\n".'Your Password is: 
'.$pass1.'';
$headers = array(
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
 );

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => '465',
'auth' => true,
'username' => 'someone@gmail.com',
'password' => '12345678'
 ));
 $mail = $smtp -> send($to, $headers, $body);

if(PEAR::isError($mail)){
echo '<p>'.$mail->getMessage().'</p>';   
}
else{
   echo "<script>alert('Successfully Registered! Your credentials have been 
sent on email that you have given in the form')</script>";
 }
```

this is my email code, in body I want to add an image/logo.

Comment: Have you tried doing / fixing this yourself first?

Comment: You're using pear mail, not [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You might want to try that.

Comment: yes I try to embed image but it is not working. and I also try doing it with <img src> but the code is showing in the message.

Comment: @Haris you need to send a header of `Content-type:text/html`.

Comment: still not working! thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Haris if you don't tag me(mention my name), I won't be notified. Secondly, in your case, you need to add this header as `'Content-Type' => 'text/html'` in your `$headers` array. Also, make sure you actually add `<img src='some_image_url'>` in your `$body` variable.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks for your guidance, its working!

Comment: @Haris you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for embedding image `AddEmbeddedImage`

you can also add an image as inline attachment with the content ID of my-photo, you would access it within the HTML body using `<img src="cid:my-photo" alt="my-photo">`.

In detail, here is the function to add an embedded attachment:

```
$mail->addEmbeddedImage($filename, $cid);
```